# C Language: Triple nested while() loop that does not work correctly

Tags: c, gcc, while-loop, nested-loops, logic-error

I want to write a code in C language to output a list of triples matching the Pythagorean triple in a range of positive integers (**a<sup>2</sup> = b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> with a, b and c ∈ ℤ<sup>+</sup>**) using only nested `while ()` loops.

I wrote this:

```
//Programme to output possible Pythagorean triples in a range of unsigned integers.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned int i = 1, j = 1, ij = 1;

    puts("\n***To calculate Pythag. triple integers...***\n");
    while (i <= 250) {
        while (j <= 250) {
            while (ij <= 250) {
                if (ij * ij == i * i + j * j) {
                    printf ("Candidate triple: (%u, %u, %u)\n", ij, i, j);
                }
                ++ij;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not work. It only shows the text in the first `puts()` function.

output:

[image]

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After ending a loop with i=1,j=1,ij=251, you never enter the innermost loop again because you never set `ij` back to `1`. Same for `j`.

Fixed:

```c
    unsigned i = 1;
    while (i <= 250){
        unsigned j = 1;
        while (j <= 250){
            unsigned ij = 1;
            while (ij <= 250){
                if (ij*ij == i*i + j*j) {
                    printf("Candidate triple: (%u, %u, %u)\n", ij, i, j);
                }
                ++ij;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
```

We usually write this as follows:

```c
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i <= 250; ++i ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 1; j <= 250; ++j ) {
            for ( unsigned ij = 1; ij <= 250; ++ij ) {
                if (ij*ij == i*i + j*j) {
                    printf("Candidate triple: (%u, %u, %u)\n", ij, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is still a while loop, but using the `for` keyword/syntax.

---

Note that it *might* be faster to precalculate the 250 squares. We can also do the additions fewer times. And we can break out of the inner loop once we find a match.

```c
    unsigned squares[251]; // 0..250
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i <= 250; ++i ) {
        squares[i] = i*i;
    }

    for ( unsigned i = 1; i <= 250; ++i ) {
        unsigned ii = squares[i];
        for ( unsigned j = 1; j <= 250; ++j ) {
            unsigned jj = squares[j];
            unsigned iipjj = ii+jj;
            for ( unsigned k = 1; k <= 250; ++k ) {
                unsigned kk = squares[k];
                if (kk == iipjj) {
                    printf("Candidate triple: (%u, %u, %u)\n", k, i, j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I don't know much about for-loops and that thing [] which might be a list or array. So I will stick to that while() for now till I reach those topics.

Answer (score 2):

After inner loop exit it's variable isn't reinitialized and remain 251. You should initialize variable inside of outer loop:

```c
   while (i <= 250){
        j = 1;
        while (j <= 250){
            ij = 1;
            while (ij <= 250){
                if (ij*ij == i*i + j*j){
                    printf ("Candidate triple: (%u, %u, %u)\n", ij, i, j);
                }
                ++ij;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
```